# Stripping HTML from Datatable SearchPanes

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to use SearchPanes with DataTables. However, as shown in the following image, there are unwanted html elements in the filter columns. How can I strip these html elements from SearchPanes. My JS code is as follows:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var table = $('.table').DataTable({
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                        {
                            extend:    'searchPanes',
                            text:      '<i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>',
                            titleAttr: 'Advanced Filters'
                        }],
                
            });
        });
    
    </script>
```

[image: unwanted html in datatable searchpane]

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show us: (a) how the table is being populated, and (b) some sample source data?  What I can see in your screenshot is only partial (invalid) HTML. This suggests there may perhaps be a problem with the source data.

Comment: thank you for the comment and I am sorry for the late reply. My page is live at http://thesis.asianindexing.com/

Answer (score 1):

### The Problem

I am not able to reproduce the *specific* problem you are facing. However, I am also not able to display hyperlinked text correctly in the search pane.

This appears to be happening because of the way the SearchPanes plug-in is working (I would call it a bug). I do not have a good solution for this. I tried using [orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data) in column a renderer, but that did not give me the correct display, either.

### My Work-Around

My suggestion is therefore to use a simple work-around:

1. For the "Supervisor" column, create a new hidden column (`visible: false`) which contains only the text - no hyperlinks: For example:

```
A S Ansari
```

2. Keep the existing "Institute" column, unchanged. For example:

```
<a href="index.php?f=Supervisor&amp;q=A S Ansari">A S Ansari</a>
```

3. In your `searchPanes` option, use the hidden column instead of the visible column.
4. Repeat the above steps for all the other column which contain linked text.

This way, your users will see names displayed with hyperlinks in the table, and they will see the plain text names in the search panes.

Filtering will work as normal - but you will be filtering based on the data in the hidden column.

In my test example, I have names displayed as links:

[image]

But the pane uses the plain text data from a hidden column:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the [renderers](https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers) together with [orthogona data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data):

```
columns: [
    {
        data: #your_data#,
        title: '#your_title#',
        searchPanes: {
            orthogonal: "sp",
        },
        render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
            if (type === "display") {
                return '<span style="color:red">' + data + "</span>";
            } else if (type === "sp") {
                return data;
            } else {
                return data;
            }
        },
    },
];
```

Comment: this doesn't work, for a start what does "data: #your_data#," refer to?
I get errored: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mData')"